# Inconsistent behavior from getUserMedia in insecure context

Tags: javascript, typescript, tensorflow.js

I am trying to build a Blazeface demo [1](https://github.com/tensorflow/tfjs-models/tree/master/blazeface/demo) myself, for the sake of learning. For example I use Webpack instead of yarn, and I drop e.g the `Stats()` and backend selector.

The original demo runs fine with `yarn watch`, but when I try to replicate the code and run `webpack-dev-server` I get a `TypeError: Cannot set property 'srcObject' of undefined` from the `getUserMedia()` call in the following function. The exception is thrown both in Chrome and Firefox.

Here is the Typescript function

```
async function setupCamera() {
    const video = document.getElementById('videoCamera') as HTMLVideoElement;
    const stream = await navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({
        'audio': false,
        'video': {facingMode: 'user'}
    });
    video.srcObject = stream;   
    return new Promise((resolve) => {
        video.onloadedmetadata = () => {
            resolve(video);
        };
    });
}
```

and this is the prettified bundled Javascript function that is read by the browser.

```
async function l() {
    const t = await navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({audio:!1,video: 
                                                        {facingMode:"user"}});
    return (void 0).srcObject = t,
    new Promise(t=>{
        (void 0).onloadedmetadata = ()=>{
                t(void 0)
        }
    }
)}
```

I understand that the error is thrown because I am using `navigator.mediaDevices` in an insecure context, that is a localhost server.

How can the Blazeface demo run without problems on localhost, while my code throws an exception?

EDIT:
perhaps useful to add the `yarn watch` script  in `package.json` I mentioned for the working solution:

```
"watch": "cross-env NODE_ENV=development parcel index.html --no-hmr"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved the issue by changing `"target": "es2017"` to `"target": "es6"` in `tsconfig.json`.